# In CakePHP, how can I see which fixtures were actually used?

Tags: cakephp

I have a test class with lots of tests. I just moved several of them to a separate test file. How can I find out which fixtures are safe to remove from the test.

Obviously, I can comment out each fixture one-by-one and see if it breaks. But I'm wondering if there is a type of log I can look at that will show which fixtures were actually used.

(If it matters I'm using the latest version of CakePHP 2, but we'll be moving to 3 soon.)

Comment: Enable logging in your database connection and grep the log file for create statements when running the test?

Comment: @burzum that doesn't tell me which ones are actually _used_. Good thought, though. I could grep logs for selects. Hoping for something simpler.